# Atomic instructions and atomic type

Tags: c++, c++11

Are there types which I can read or modify or compare atomically by default?
Or should I use atomic operations explicitly for ALL types for ALL operations?

Comment: @Damon I think you should put that as answer

Comment: `std::atomic<T>` is a type that you always read and modify atomically (to be precise, conversion to `T` automatically performs an atomic load, and assignment from `T` performs an atomic store). I'm not sure what you mean by "compare atomically".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should **always** use atomic types or atomic operations if you need atomicity. Never anything different.

Formally, no non-atomic type provides any kind of atomic access by default. In reality, with current CPUs, any builtin type can be read and written (but not modified) atomically. However, this is not something you have a guarantee for, and definitely not something you should rely on. It is merely an implementation detail.
All reads and writes on current CPUs go through a cache. Only complete cache lines (usually something around 64-128 bytes) can be read from main memory or written back, and cache lines are multiples of the size of the biggest builtin type. Which means that if a type is properly aligned, it is necessarily contained within a single cache line, which automatically makes reading or writing it atomic. However, *modifying* a value is a read-modify-write operation, which implies that even if each step is atomic as such, the whole operation isn't.

There's much more to atomicity than just being able to atomically read (or modify) a value, for example there are ordering guarantees that you may need for correctness. Even if reads and writes are atomic, your code will not work properly if modifications are not seen by a different processor in the order that you expected. Compilers and CPUs are (within some reasonable limits) allowed to reorder instructions, including loads and stores. This can, however, mean that your code will not execute correctly.

Atomic operations therefore have a "memory model" associated with them, which allows you to provide additional information on what happens-before guarantees you need between threads and between related or unrelated data. See the [GCC Wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) for a good description of every mode.
By default, atomic operations choose the *sequentially consistent* model, which is the safest mode with the strictest limitations. You may choose a different model if you know that you do not need certain guarantees, which may (or may not, depending on the architecture) result in more performant code being generated.
The nice thing with memory models is that they abstract implementation details, architectural pecularities, and compiler voodoo into a form that decribes your algorithmic requirements, and guarantee that these requirements are met.

Often, the compiler will be able use normal non-atomic machine instructions and still guarantee that your requirements are met (it might have to forfeit one or the other reordering). This depends on the actual details of how the target hardware works and what guarantees you need.
All in all, the use of atomics and memory models is not only more comfortable, and less failure-prone than botching with it manually on a low level (inline assembler), it is also likely the most performant approach possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic.

It mentions of `std::atomic<T>`, just like @IgorTandetnik mention in one of the comments.